# the amplitude-frequency spectrum and the phase-frequency spectrum of a coherent packet of radio pulse

Tags: signal-analysis, coherence

Who can tell you how to draw the amplitude-frequency spectrum and the phase-frequency spectrum of a coherent packet of radio pulses?

Comment: Maybe [related](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/74139/50076).

Comment: Thank you!!!!!!