# How to calculate the instantaneous frequency for one specfic signal?

Tags: signal-analysis, frequency

I have a signal which like this:
[image]
I want to calculate this signal's instantaneous frequency.I have tried hht and so on which method I can find but can not get the result.
So does somebody can give me some advice? If can proveide some python program which will be must useful for me.Thanks!

UPDATED:
Thanks @OverLordGoldDragon
I use this code in [this answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/74024/estimation-of-amplitude-frequency-and-phase-of-linear-combination-of-harmonic-s/74139#74139):

```
import numpy as np
from ssqueezepy import ssq_cwt, extract_ridges
from ssqueezepy.visuals import plot, imshow

# z = see OP's code; used np.random.seed(1000)

beta = 24
Tx, Wx, ssq_freqs, scales, *_ = ssq_cwt(z, ('gmw', {'beta': beta}), padtype='zero', fs=6)
ridge_idxs = extract_ridges(Tx, scales, penalty=20)

plot(ridge_idxs, color='k', linestyle='--', xlims=(0, len(z) - 1))
imshow(Tx, abs=1, yticks=ssq_freqs[::-1], ylabel="Frequencies [Hz]",
       title="abs(SSQ_CWT), wavelet=('gmw', {'beta': %s})" % beta)
amplitude = np.abs(Tx[ridge_idxs[:, 0], np.arange(len(z))])
frequencies = ssq_freqs[::-1][ridge_idxs[:, 0]]

plot(amplitude, ylims=(0, None), title="Amplitude vs time, SSQ ridge", show=1)
plot(frequencies, ylims=(0, None), ylabel="Frequencies [Hz]", 
     title="Frequency vs time, SSQ ridge", show=1)
```

But my result like this:
[image]
Which seems disorder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Synchrosqueezing](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/71398/synchrosqueezing-wavelet-transform-explanation/71399#71399) with [ssqueezepy](https://github.com/OverLordGoldDragon/ssqueezepy).

[image]

```
from ssqueezepy import TestSignals, ssq_cwt
from ssqueezepy.visuals import plot, imshow

x = TestSignals(N=2048).lchirp()[0]
Tx, _, ssq_freqs, *_ = ssq_cwt(x)
plot(x, title="linear chirp", show=1)
imshow(Tx, abs=1, title="abs(SSQ_CWT)", xlabel="time", ylabel="frequency",
       yticks=ssq_freqs[::-1])
```

Comment: Thanks for you help! Dose ssqueezepy has some docs? I'm a newer for signal processing. I want to know which is the result of signal's instantaneous frequency and how to use this. Thanks again!

Comment: @user57947 Every library function is documented, e.g. `help(ssq_cwt)`. There's lots of reference material in the README, including [this overview](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/71399/50076), and [examples](https://github.com/OverLordGoldDragon/ssqueezepy/tree/master/examples). For choosing wavelet parameters, see [here](https://overlordgolddragon.github.io/test-signals/).

Comment: @user57947 There's also [learning resources](https://github.com/OverLordGoldDragon/ssqueezepy#learning-resources) ("DSP Fundamentals"), beginner friendly.

Comment: Thanks,I think what I need may be in Tx, But I found Tx is a multi dimension array. So what  dimension is the instantaneous frequency?

Comment: @user57947 dim0 is frequency, dim1 is time. If you prefer a 1D array, can be done with ridge extraction - see [this answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/74139/50076).

Comment: I had use the code you answered in that question.But I got the result like the updated in my question.I think this may not correct.

Comment: @user57947 That means parameters in `ssq_cwt` or `extract_ridges` need adjusting. But this is now a separate question, which you're free to ask - best with signal data included for download, as `.npy` or `.csv` (or paste as list [here](https://pastebin.com/) if reasonably long).

Comment: Thanks! I had paste the first part(which is the limit max size) of data in [here](https://pastebin.com/0X0qwRsA).

Comment: @user57947 You should ask a [new question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/ask), now about "instantaneous frequency vs time as 1D array". That data isn't really enough, try [here](https://ufile.io/), or share it fully with multiple pastebins.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think I had got it which as what you said change the parameters in `ssq_cwt` and `extract_ridges`.If I have some new questions I will ask you again. So please don't bored with me!